# How to use a parameter in a macro call?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I have defined the following simple macro:

```
 (defmacro define-class (class-name)
  `(defclass ,class-name ()()))
```

And now I want to use it in the following function:

```
(defun create-data (mode)
  (define-class mode))
```

After compiling the last function I get the following message, *the variable MODE is defined but never used*.

And when I execute the function to create a class "myclass", I get instead the creation of a class of type "mode":

```
 (create-data 'myclass)
 #<STANDARD-CLASS MODE>
```

Seems that my argument is not used? How can I get the function *create-data* to use the argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
CL-USER 86 >  (defmacro define-class (class-name)
                `(defclass ,class-name ()()))
DEFINE-CLASS

CL-USER 87 > (defun create-data (mode)
               (funcall (compile nil `(lambda ()
                                        (define-class ,mode)))))
CREATE-DATA

CL-USER 88 > (create-data 'bar)
#<STANDARD-CLASS BAR 402016CC73>
```

Above uses code generation and the built-in compiler.

Comment: Thank you. It works properly. Somehow in this solution you built an intermediate macro between the function and the macro. I find it nice, even if i never met the _compile_ command before. That makes me think that there must be something wrong in the way i implemented my code.

Answer (score 3):

`defclass` isn't a function but a macro. It uses the name provided in the source (mode in your case) and it's not the same as your variable `mode`. In fact some CL implementations would warn you that argument `mode` is never used.

You can macroexpand it `(macroexpand '(defclass mode ()()))` to check what it becomes in your implementation. I get this in CLISP (I've cleaned it up a little):

```
(progn
  (eval-when (compile load eval)
    (apply #'ensure-class 
           'mode ; notice mode is quoted
           :direct-superclasses (list) 
           :direct-slots (list) 
           :metaclass clos::<standard-class>
           (append '(:fixed-slot-locations nil) 
                    (list :direct-default-initargs nil 
                          :documentation nil 
                          :generic-accessors 't))))
  (find-class 'mode)) ; notice mode is quoted
```

The expansion is imlementation dependent but the result is the same in all. `mode` is the name of the class being defined and not what you pass as argument.

You should use `(define-class myclass)` instead of `(create-data 'myclass)`.

Comment: This solution work if i call directly the macro, but doesn't work if i call the macro through the function create-data like this for e.g: (create-data myclass).

Comment: @Xaving Yes, and my answer shows why. `defclass` is a macro that does NOT take variables but it's class name as a constant. I think this question is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and that the real solution is neither my nor Rainers hacking. That you can do something doesn't mean you should. Macros that don't expand before runtime smells.